# Creating sub-menu headers in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

I am creating a customer DotNetNuke(DNN) skin - and one of the things I'd like to do is have sub-menu groupings.

For example:

- **LIFE**
    __LIVING IN WIDGETVILLE__
  - GETTING AROUND

    HOUSE PRICES

    SCHOOL INFORMATION

Where:

LIFE is the main menu item

LIVING IN WIDGETVILLE is just a description or group for the sub-menu items. I could have other groupings below those, but juts vertically not nested group descriptions.

Each of the bulleted items below group description are actual menu links.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some menu modules out there tat could do that for you might look on Snowcovered.com - you could also just write a small menu to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option after thinking of it is to add extra pages that are disabled  that are one the site - not sure what you are trying achieve but that division really isnt part of the menu but the structure of the site

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by adding the following to my ASCX skin file -

```
<%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(0).TabName%>
```